# Activity transition animation not working on Pixel 3

Tags: android, animation

I'm developing an Android App which has both a portrait activity and a landscape activity. The rotate animation works well on most kinds of phones like Samsung, Huawei, and Xiaomi, etc. But when it comes to Google Pixel 3(Android 11) and OnePlus, there is no rotate animation in transition. Can someone please help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please share your code that performs the animation

Comment: I didn't write the animation. Instead, I just set one activity as portrait and the other as landscape in the AndroidManifest.xml. I think it's using the default animation of the system but it's not working on some kinds of phones.